# Powershell fails at pgp decryption

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, pgp

I am trying to decrpyt the automated pgp message with powershell however it drops an error message: "gpg: decrypt_message failed: No such file or directory"

The sign and encryption part was done with command line commands:

```
$path = "\\networkdrive\folder1\message"
$step2files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path | Where-Object{$_.Extension -eq ".asc"}
$z=1
foreach ($files in $step2files) {
    $outputname = "$files.pgp"
    $input = $files
    $z 

    $options = " --output $outputname –-encrypt --recipient XYKey $files"
    $options

    gpg  --output $outputname --encrypt --recipient XYKey $input
    $z++
}
```

I need the response decrypted in a similar way and even though powershell finds all the respective files, the aforementioned error message displays.

The codepart is:

```
$extracted = "\\networkdrive\folder1\extracted"
$step5files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $extracted | Where-Object{$_.Extension -eq ".pgp"}
$z=1
foreach ($files in $step5files) {
    $outputname = "$files.xml"
    $input = $files
    $z 

    $options = " -u KeyID --batch --yes --passphrase password --output $outputname --decrypt $files"
    $options

    gpg  -u KeyID --batch --yes --passphrase password --output $outputname --decrypt $input
    $z++
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Post Full Error please

Comment: The full error message is:
gpg: can't open `MyEncryptedFile.pgp': No such file or directory
gpg: decrypt_message failed: No such file or directory

The bottleneck of this task is that I cannot install anything (such as GnuPG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using latest GnuPG, this works fine on my end:

```
 $cipher =  "My secret message"  | gpg -ear 'MyRecipient'

 Write-Host $chipher 

 $message = $cipher | gpg --batch --yes --passphrase 'MyPassphrase'

 Write-Host $message
```